# Accessing data in nested JSON array using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

For some reason, I am having trouble accessing specific values of the following nested array:

```
[{
    "call_sign": "KTAB-TV",
    "facility_id": "59988",
    "operator": "Nexstar Media Group Inc",
    "programming_class": [{
        "primary": {
            "programming": "CBS",
            "resolution": "1080i",
            "resolution_type": "HD",
            "programming_classifier": "HD1"
        },
        "d_2": {
            "programming": "Telemundo",
            "resolution": "480i",
            "resolution_type": "SD",
            "programming_classifier": "SD1"
        },
        "d_3": {
            "programming": "Escape",
            "resolution": "480i",
            "resolution_type": "SD",
            "programming_classifier": "SD2"
        },
        "d_4": {
            "programming": "ION",
            "resolution": "480i",
            "resolution_type": "SD",
            "programming_classifier": "SD3"
        },
        "d_5": {
            "programming": "None",
            "resolution": "NULL",
            "resolution_type": "N\/A",
            "programming_classifier": "None"
        },
        "d-6": {
            "programming": "None",
            "resolution": "NULL",
            "resolution_type": "N\/A",
            "programming_classifier": "None"
        }
    }]
}]
```

Right now, my best guess is the following:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "prep_station_data.php?sid=" + sid,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('success');
        for (key in data) {
            var value = data[key];
            console.log(value);
        }
        $.getJSON(jsonURL, function(key, value) {
            var resolutions = '';
            $.each(data[0].programming_class, function(key, value) {
                resolutions += value.resolution;

            });
            $('#primary_programming').append(resolutions);
        });
    },
    complete: function() {}
});
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm still getting an "undefined" result.

In addition, I would love any insights on how I could create an if statement in jquery that populates a div if the `programming_classifier` key in the json data array is a specific value.

Thanks for any assistance as I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

`programming_class` is also an array with a single element. So...

`data[0].programming_class[0]`

Here's a working data handling function.

```js
$(function() {

    var json = '[{"call_sign":"KTAB-TV","facility_id":"59988","operator":"Nexstar Media Group Inc","programming_class":[{"primary":{"programming":"CBS","resolution":"1080i","resolution_type":"HD","programming_classifier":"HD1"},"d_2":{"programming":"Telemundo","resolution":"480i","resolution_type":"SD","programming_classifier":"SD1"},"d_3":{"programming":"Escape","resolution":"480i","resolution_type":"SD","programming_classifier":"SD2"},"d_4":{"programming":"ION","resolution":"480i","resolution_type":"SD","programming_classifier":"SD3"},"d_5":{"programming":"None","resolution":"NULL","resolution_type":"N/A","programming_classifier":"None"},"d-6":{"programming":"None","resolution":"NULL","resolution_type":"N/A","programming_classifier":"None"}}]}]';

    function handleData(data) {
        var pc = data[0]['programming_class'][0];
        var ret = [];
        for (var i in pc) {
            if (pc.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                for (var j in pc[i]) {
                    if (pc[i].hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                        if (j == 'resolution') {
                            ret.push(pc[i][j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    var stuff = handleData(JSON.parse(json));

    $('#content').text(stuff.join(', '));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  That gave me enough to figure out my issues.  Time to move forward!

Answer (score 1):

First: the callback of getJSON does not return `(key, value)` it will rteurn `(parseArray, successString) =>` so your loop will not run.  Check below, a possible solution can be :-

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5c7e2d275fe214587796753b", (data) => {
  
  // $.getJSON callback format returns  (data, status)
  // so if you get it as (key, value) you will get (Your JSON Array, "success") 
  // Solution is below
  
  data.forEach((value, key) => {
      if(value.programming_class){
          // programming class is an array in provided JSON
          // you can use static first index as well if it is fixed
          // value = value[0] to avoid  outer loop;
          value.programming_class.forEach((p) => {
              // p is not an array
              let keys = Object.keys(p);
              keys.forEach((k) => {
                  let classObj = p[k];
                  console.log(classObj);
                  // now you can perform actions on this object i-e: sum, multiple whatever
              });
          });
      }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks.  This might have worked as well but I was able to get what I needed from the first responder.

Answer (score -1):

thats because you forgot to add this, `JSON.parse()`, 
when you get results from the server it returns as text or unformatted json string, 
you have to pass it through that function for javascript to render properly..

so here we'd have -

```
 success: function(data) {

        data = JSON.parse(data);

        console.log('success');
        for (key in data) {
            var value = data[key];

    ...
```

Note that, when receiving data from a web server, the data is always a string. i hope this helps.